# How to keep my brain active and alert in natural always

Tags: brain, cognitive-science, brain-exercises, alertness-level, forgetfulness

Could you please let me know if any foods available to keep our brain active and alert always.

Sometimes I loss the common sense also to think on few things. For example pronouncing a word that I already know in wrong way. I also forget regular things like locking doors, turning off lights etc. very poor listening skills. I think the common problem for all these is because of low functionality of my brain.

Is there any way to improve my brain usage. Thanks in advance.

I am a vegeterian

Comment: It is not possible to be always happy for me. My work involves analytical thinking. I need to think a lot in different ways until I get the solutions within the given time limit in my job. May be this is the cause for these mistakes, but I can't avoid my job.

Comment: More likely this isn't a nutritional thing. Thinking you can solve these types of problems by simply eating something else is often looking for an easy way out that's doomed to be ineffective. Not that nutrition isn't important, but other things to add: Hobbies, physical activity, mental activity (puzzles, etc), reading, social interaction, therapy, rest, structure, and avoid things that have sort of been bringing brain functions down as a society over the past decade; avoid getting sucked in to the mindless quick-reward mobile games, for example, look for more challenging games. Etc.

Comment: (It's sort of like how people like to pretend that switching to diet soda is that magic solution to physical health that they've been missing all this time.) PS on the mobile game front I suppose there's stuff like Lumosity ([YMMV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumosity#Effectiveness_and_legal_history)). And of course the possibility that this is just not one of your strong points, which is fine, so you'll have to find ways to accept / work around it.

Comment: It has been proven that [physical exercise](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2016/jun/18/how-physical-exercise-makes-your-brain-work-better) is better than solving crossword puzzles, chess riddles and alike. Just in case you want to keep your brain active in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For activity you need energy, try eating foods that contain polysaccharides. That's what  athletes eat before triathlon. 
Reference : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate

Monosaccharides help for short time energy boost although they can turn into fats if not used.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. Wikipedia is not a reliable reference...